# Advice on dynamically combining mpeg-dash mpd data

Tags: mpeg-dash, media-source, mpd

I'm doing research for a project that's about to start.

We will be supplied hundreds of 30 second video files that the end user can select (via various filters) we then want to play them as if it was one video.

It seems that Media Source Extensions with MPEG-DASH is the way to go.

I feel like it could possibly be solve in the following way, but **I'd like to ask if this sounds right from anyone who has done similar things**

**My theory:**

Create mpd's for each video (via mp4box or similar tool)

User make selections (each of which has a mpd)

Read each mpd and get their `<period>` elements (most likely only one in each)

Create a new mpd file and insert all the `<period>` elements into it in order.

**Caveats**

I imagine this may be problematic if the videos were all different sizes formats etc, but in this case we can assume consistency.

**So my question is to anyone with mpeg-dash / mpd exterience, does this sound right? or is there a better way to acheive this?**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds right, multi period is the only feasible way in my opinion.
Ideally you would encode all the videos with the same settings to provide the end user a consistent experience. However, it shouldn't be a problem if quality or even aspect ratio etc change from one period to another from a technical point of view. You'll need a player which supports multi period, such as [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/) or [Bitmovin](https://bitmovin.com/video-player/).

Comment: So got it working, it was quite a process but all possible. The details are completely situational but I wrote a description of my precess here https://medium.com/@rburnie/merging-video-stream-data-54442cc6ea59